# Pattern matching of parsed html with poor tag implementation to retrieve information with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, parsing, pattern-matching, jsoup

i am using java with jsoup to parse a website, trouble is , alot of the information i needed isnt surrounded by tags.

for example , each `<p>` below has telephone number/s for 2 different people. one person has a telephone while the other does not.

```
<p class="contact-info">Tel: <strong> 059-9162997</strong> | Mob: <strong>087-2280039</strong></p>
 <p class="contact-info">Mob: <strong>086 7726712</strong></p>
```

How could i parse/ pattern match this information to retrieve

person 1 -----> 059-9162997, 087-2280039

person 2 -----> 086 7726712

Also how would i retrieve the information for this

```
<p class="contact-info">Address: <strong>Suite 26, Unit 1, North Park, North Road,Dublin 11, Dublin</strong> <br />Email: <a href="mailto:info@swillydrive.ie">info@swillydrive.ie</a><br />Website: <a href="http://www.swillydrive.ie">http://www.swillydrive.ie</a></p>
```

where

Address ----->Suite 26, Unit 1, North Park, North Road,Dublin 11, Dublin
email -------> info@swillydrive.ie
website ------>http://www.swillydrive.ie

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jsoup to select some data depending on what you need, as described [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

In your case, you need to select all `p` tag with the `contact-info` class, and then the `strong` tag in it. The syntax allows you do write it like this:

```
p.contact-info strong
```

Which, in Java, gives:

```
Elements elements = document.select("p.contact-info strong");
for (Element element : elements) {
    String phoneNumber = element.text();
}
```